# Create a cookie with PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I don't understand where is my mistake:

Page `a.php`:

```
setcookie("user",$username,time()+300);
```

Page `b.php`:

`echo $_COOKIE['user'];` or `echo $_COOKIE["user"];`

The result is that `echo` doesn't print nothing!

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Are both files in the same folder? Have you tried also setting the path for the cookie?

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled in your browser?

Comment: I've not used cookies before but try a `var_dump()` rather than echo when testing variables

Comment: Yes, I have cookies enabled in my browser and yes two pages are in the same folder. Now I try with the path

Comment: is `$username`  null or empty string?7

Comment: use something like httpfox or firebug's net tab to make sure the cookie header is actually being sent over to the browser, and see what's in the browser's cookie store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `$username` has no value or you have white-space before you are setting the cookie. Cookies must be sent with the header information before any HTML is sent at all so make sure the

Comment: @user2467899 are you sure there isnt even one empty space before the tags?